# Apps Script parameters with script.google.run

Tags: google-apps-script

With Apps Script, it's not allowed to use iframes or AJAX calls. So, I was hoping to restructure my script. Basically, it's just supposed to be a single file chooser.

```
function doGet(e)
{
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}


function browse(e)
{
  var use_root_folder = typeof(e.parameter.folder_id) == "undefined";

  var base_folder;
  if(use_root_folder)
  {
    base_folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  }
  else
  {
    base_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(e.parameter.folder_id);
  }
  //more code...
}
```

In sample code on apps script, it looks like I'm supposed to create an html file and put this in it...

```
<script>
  google.script.run.browse();
</script>
```

Except the "e" argument is only available from within the actual script and not the html file? How would I go about passing a query string parameter from within the HTML file back to the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using google.script.run, you pass variables directly. So you can simply call browser() with the ID of the folder you want.

In the script file:

```
function browse(folderID)
{
  var use_root_folder = typeof(folderID) == "undefined";

  var base_folder;
  if(use_root_folder)
  {
    base_folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  }
  else
  {
    base_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  }
  //more code...
}
```

And in the HTML file:

```
<script>
  google.script.run.browse(selectedFolderId);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks...what's not really clear from the documentation is that top-level vars are exposed from within the template <? ?> code...I ended up just putting stuff at the top level and managing it that way.

So while I knew I could pass something like selectedFolderId to my fn...I didn't know that if I put selectedFolderId at top-level scope that it would be exposed to the template